# Track data usage

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to track the data usage from the user of the iPhone.

But I'am loose I found this:

```
- (NSArray *)getDataCounters {
BOOL   success;
struct ifaddrs *addrs;
const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
const struct if_data *networkStatisc; 

int WiFiSent = 0;
int WiFiReceived = 0;
int WWANSent = 0;
int WWANReceived = 0;

NSString *name=[[[NSString alloc]init]autorelease];

success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
if (success) 
{
    cursor = addrs;
    while (cursor != NULL) 
    {
        name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];
        NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);
        // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN 

        if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK) 
        {
            if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"]) 
            {
                networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                WiFiSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                WiFiReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                NSLog(@"WiFiSent %d ==%d",WiFiSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                NSLog(@"WiFiReceived %d ==%d",WiFiReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
            }

            if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"]) 
            {
                networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                WWANSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                WWANReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                NSLog(@"WWANSent %d ==%d",WWANSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                NSLog(@"WWANReceived %d ==%d",WWANReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
            } 
        }

        cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
    }

    freeifaddrs(addrs);
}       

return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiSent], [NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiReceived],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANSent],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANReceived], nil];
```

}

But how could i do it automatically, each time the user call the web browser I intersect the size of the package

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for Logging or Analytics

Logging : Just NSLog or write to an array and periodicly save to file

Analytics : Check out [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) it's a good user experience tracking program

Comment: I am looking for track the data usage from the entire device in an iPhone

Comment: you want to track the users interaction with all apps? if so that breaks Apples Terms and would be rejected from the store

Comment: Yes I want to do that, but why DataMan or DataUsage exist?

Comment: Are you planning on sending the information to a web service or store it locally?

Comment: Just store it and analyzed it

Comment: Thats fine it shouldn't be a problem i was under the impression you wanted to log it and send the info to a webserver

Comment: no I think apple will reject it. but do u have any idea how to do this?

Comment: no i've never considered logging the activity of other apps before sorry