# How to get Wifi and cellular datausage in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Track data usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139138/track-data-usage)

how can we get the iphone wifi and cellularv datausage like data sent and receive using wifi and wwan.

Comment: here is the solution for my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139138/track-data-usage

Answer (score 1):

If you use CFNetwork classes for network communication, you can record data usage for your application, as http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ does for throttling bandwidth.

For global data usage, I do not believe that is available in the iOS SDK, but some folks seem to have dropped down to accessing the ifconfig for this:

[iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring)